# Can't clear the white spaces with the most common methods

Tags: c#, string

This is the case - I need to work with the `Text` property of a `ToolStripItem` and I need to clear all white spaces from the string before that. However I tried three very common (in my opinion) scenarios and neither of them returned a string with no white spaces. Here is what I tried:

```
string tempBtnText = tempItem.Text;
```

`tempBtnText` is defined inside the method where I work with the `Text` property. I find it easier this way. Then I tried those:

```
tempBtnText.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
tempBtnText = Regex.Replace(tempItem.Text, @"^\s*$\n", string.Empty);
string tempBtnTexts = Regex.Replace(tempItem.Text, @"\s+", "");
```

All those returned the string in it's original form (with white spaces). The only way to remove the white spaces was by using this method :

```
public string RemoveWhitespace(string input)
{
    return new string(input.ToCharArray()
        .Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
        .ToArray());
}
```

Which I found in a similar post here in `SO`. but I really don't understand why all of the above approaches don't work. I'm starting to think that there is something to do with the fact that I'm using a `ToolStripItem` Text property but as shown at the very begining I declare my own string variable that takes the value of the `Text` property and.

I don't know. Can someone tell me, what is the reason of this behavior. Not that it's that big of a problem to use another method for clearing the white spaces but the not working options are much more compact and readable and I would like to use one of them if possible.

Comment: Note that in the first condition you're not taking the result.. `tempBtnText=tempBtnText.Replace();`

Comment: I believe it would be useful to see a test case (example value of `textBtnText`) here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Strings are immutable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx), what means that any operation produces a new instance, so you need assign any method result back to input:

```
string input = "...";
intput = intput.Replace(x, y);
```

Comment: Thanks the assigning really fixed this one but in th `RegEx` example I'm assigning the result but it doesn't work even so. Any idea about this case?

Answer (score 2):

You are not assigning the result back to `tempBtnText`

```
tempBtnText.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
```

it should be:

```
tempBtnText = tempBtnText.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
```

strings are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), `string.Replace` returns a new string, it doesn't modify the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

abatischev is right so writing

```
tempBtnText = tempBtnText.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
```

should solve your problems. If you only want to remove Whitespaces in front and back then rather use:

```
tempBtnText = tempBtnText.Trim();
```